# Comparing number of identical column elements between two rows in Python

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy, element

I am trying to write a basic script that will help me to find how many similar columns there are between rows. The information is very simple, something like:

```
array = np.array([0 1 0 0 1 0 0], [0 0 1 0 1 1 0])
```

I would have to execute this script between all permutations of the list, so row 1 compared to row 2, row 1 compared to row 3, etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where's the desired output for your example? And what row 3 are you talking about? I only see two rows. And your code is invalid.

Comment: How do you define "similar"?

Answer (score 0):

Your headline question can be addressed with basic numpy techniques. Let's assume you have a two-d numpy array `a` and you want to compare rows `m` and `n`:

```
row_m = a[m, :] # this selects row index m and all column indices, thus: row m
row_n = a[n, :]
shared = row_m == row_n # this compares row_m and row_n element-by-element storing each individual result (True or False) in a separate cell, the result thus has the same shape as row_m and row_n
overlap = shared.sum() # this sums over all elements in shared, since False is encoded as 0 and True as 1 this returns the number of shared elements.
```

The easiest way of applying this recipe to all pairs of rows is broadcasting:

```
 first = a[:, None, :] # None creates a new dimension to make space for a second row axis
 second = a[None, :, :] # Same but new dim in first axis
 # observe that axes 0 and 1 in these two array are arranged as for a distance map
 # a binary operation between arrays so layed out will trigger broadcasting, i.e. numpy will compute all possible pairs in the appropriate positions
 full_overlap_map = first == second # has shape nrow x nrow x ncol
 similarity_table = full_overlap_map.sum(axis=-1) # shape nrow x nrow
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can rely on all rows being binary valued the "similar columns" count is simply

```
def count_sim_cols(row0, row1):
    return np.sum(row0*row1)
```

If there's the possibility of a wider range of values, you would just replace the product with a comparison

```
def count_sim_cols(row0, row1):
     return np.sum(row0 == row1)
```

If you would like a tolerance on "similarity", say `tol`, some small value, this is just

```
def count_sim_cols(row0, row1):
    return np.sum(np.abs(row0 - row1) < tol)
```

Then you can double-nested loop to get the counts. Assuming `X` is a numpy array with `n` rows

```
sim_counts = {}
for i in xrange(n):
    for j in xrange(i + 1, n):
        sim_counts[(i, j)] = count_sim_cols(X[i], X[j])
```